# How does the dataflow for importing a text file to a SQL Server table in SSIS work?

Tags: text, import, ssis, dataflow

How does the dataflow for importing a text file to a SQL Server table in SSIS work?  There is a separate bulk insert task so it is probably not using that.  Kind of interested in the actual work behind the scenes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please go through this ,to understand how the data flow works

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms140080.aspx

Bulk insert helps to import the text file into ssis.If you use the Bulkinsert task(It is one of the control flow tasks) then you do not need to define a dataflow.You can define source and destination inside the Task itself!